# Open Api Spec dynamic default value

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, openapi

I've declared query params that represent a time range (from_date and to_date) and I would like provide *dynamic* default values, at least in the swagger-ui.

from_date = last_week, to_date = today

Currently the spec will be generated within fast-api (python)
and when I publish the Api, the default values stay the same until I restart the server. The to_date would be 2022-12-01 until I restart the server, but I would like to have to_date = 2022-12-02 if I open the swagger-ui tomorrow.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but have a look at what is described here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/ _"A FastAPI application (instance) has an `.openapi()` method that is expected to return the OpenAPI schema."_ and _"By default, what the method `.openapi()` does is check the property `.openapi_schema` to see if it has contents and return them."_ ... it seems like they generate the schema and cache it on `app.openapi_schema` attribute, but you could maybe change that to invalidate the cache every midnight when dates should change